# NanoVG LWJGL3 Font Rendering

Tags: java, lwjgl

I dont really know why after some time my app crash or it's give EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, maybe i'm just bad using nvg memory but anyway if there are someone that can improve this code please help:

```
private void loadFont() {
        try {
            ByteBuffer fontData = readFileToByteBuffer("/textures/fonts/" + fontName + ".ttf");
            ByteBuffer fontNameData = MemoryUtil.memUTF8(fontName);

            if (nvgCreateFontMem(nvg, fontNameData, fontData, false) == -1) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to load font: " + fontName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ByteBuffer readFileToByteBuffer(String resourcePath) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) {
            if (inputStream == null) {
                System.err.println("Font file not found: " + resourcePath);
                return BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(0);
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            buffer.flush();
            byte[] fontBytes = buffer.toByteArray();

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(fontBytes.length);
            byteBuffer.put(fontBytes);
            byteBuffer.flip();

            return byteBuffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(0);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this to load the font from the jar itself but seems it's work but then crash because of the bad memory usage ig